# (Solidity) Error when trying to transfer ether in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

The error:

> transact to newPolice.payFine errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

The error is in function `payFine`.

Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
import "https://github.com/bokkypoobah/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary/blob/master/contracts/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.sol";

contract newPolice {
    using BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary for uint; 
    
    struct userDriver {
        string name;
        uint yearStartedDriving;
        uint accidentsCount;
        uint unpayedFines;
        uint insurance;
        uint driverBalance;
        address driverAddress;
    }
    struct vehicle {
        string vehicleCategory;
        uint price;
        uint periodOfUse;
        bool vehicleRegistrated;
        address driverAddress;
    }
    struct driverId {
        uint driverIdNumber;
        uint driverIdExpireDate;
        string vehicleCategory;
        address driverAddress;
    }
    struct time {
        uint fineTime;
    }
    
    mapping (address => userDriver) private userDriverMapping;
    mapping (address => driverId) private driverIdMapping;
    mapping (uint => driverId) private uintDriverIdMapping;
    mapping (address => vehicle) private vehicleRegistrationRequestMapping;
    mapping (address => time) private fineTimeMapping;
    
    address payable bank = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2;
    
    function driverAddData(string memory _name, uint _yearStartedDriving, uint _accidentsCount, uint _unpayedFines, uint _insurance) public {
        userDriverMapping[msg.sender] = userDriver(_name, _yearStartedDriving, _accidentsCount, _unpayedFines, _insurance, (msg.sender).balance, msg.sender);
    }
    
    function driverAddIdData(uint _driverIdNumber, uint _year, uint _month, uint _day, string memory _driverIdVehicleCategory) public {
        if (msg.sender == userDriverMapping[msg.sender].driverAddress) {
            driverIdMapping[msg.sender] = driverId(_driverIdNumber, BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.timestampFromDate(_year, _month, _day), _driverIdVehicleCategory, msg.sender);
            uintDriverIdMapping[_driverIdNumber] = driverId(_driverIdNumber, BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.timestampFromDate(_year, _month, _day), _driverIdVehicleCategory, msg.sender);
        }
    }
    
    function driverVehicalRegistrationRequest(string memory _vehicleCategory, uint _price, uint _periodOfUse) public {
        if ((msg.sender == userDriverMapping[msg.sender].driverAddress) && (keccak256(abi.encode(_vehicleCategory)) == keccak256(abi.encode(driverIdMapping[msg.sender].vehicleCategory)))) {
            vehicleRegistrationRequestMapping[msg.sender] = vehicle(_vehicleCategory, _price, _periodOfUse, true, msg.sender);
        }
    }

    function driverIdTimeExtension(uint _year, uint _month, uint _day) public payable returns(string memory) {
        if (((block.timestamp < (driverIdMapping[msg.sender].driverIdExpireDate) - (4 weeks))) && (userDriverMapping[msg.sender].unpayedFines == 0)) {
            driverIdMapping[msg.sender].driverIdExpireDate = ((BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.timestampFromDate(_year, _month, _day) - block.timestamp) + (BokkyPooBahsDateTimeLibrary.timestampFromDate(_year, _month, _day)));
        } else {
            return 'No';
        }
    }
    
    function addFine(uint _driverIdNumber) public {
        if (_driverIdNumber == uintDriverIdMapping[_driverIdNumber].driverIdNumber){
            ++userDriverMapping[uintDriverIdMapping[_driverIdNumber].driverAddress].unpayedFines;
            fineTimeMapping[msg.sender].fineTime = block.timestamp;
        }
    }
    // Error in function payFine
    uint transferMoney = 10 ether;
    function payFine() public payable {
        if (((fineTimeMapping[msg.sender].fineTime - 25) > block.timestamp) && (userDriverMapping[msg.sender].unpayedFines != 0)){
            bank.transfer(transferMoney);
            --userDriverMapping[msg.sender].unpayedFines;
        } else if (userDriverMapping[msg.sender].unpayedFines != 0){
            --userDriverMapping[msg.sender].unpayedFines;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the contract hold the 10 ETH ?

Comment: I don't know this